# Most appropriate syntax to silence warning and proper coding technique

Tags: swift

What would be a better way of writing the following code/silence the warning `Variable 'albumArt' was written to, but never read` Xcode is generating

In

```
func getCurrentlyPlayedInfo() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let songInfo = self.mediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
      self.songNameLabel.text = songInfo.title ?? ""
      self.songAlbumLabel.text = songInfo.albumTitle ?? ""
      self.songArtistLabel.text = songInfo.artist ?? ""

      //This line generates the warning
      if var albumArt = self.albumArtImageView?.image {
      albumArt = songInfo.artwork?.image(at: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)) ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyArtworkImage")
      //

    }
  }
}
```

For context, this func is updating the app's UI with the currently playing song Title, Album, Artist and Album Artwork.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. *Why* do you assign a value to `albumArt` if that value is never used in the function?

Comment: @MartinR I apologize, I forgot a line of code when I retyped it in SO. Essentially, `self.mediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem` contains all the information of the currently playing song. For albumArt I am getting the image from `songInfo.Artwork?` and setting it in AlbumArt which goes to the unwrapped Image View

Comment: The question remains. Unless I am overlooking something, the line `albumArt = ...` has no effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it was giving warning because you assigning a value to a variable albumArt which is not used further below is the warning less version of the above code:

```
    func getCurrentlyPlayedInfo() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let songInfo = self.mediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
          self.songNameLabel.text = songInfo.title ?? ""
          self.songAlbumLabel.text = songInfo.albumTitle ?? ""
          self.songArtistLabel.text = songInfo.artist ?? ""

        if let _ = self.albumArtImageView.image {
     _ = songInfo.artwork?.image(at: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)) ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "emptyArtworkImage")
      //

    }
      }
    }
```

Comment: That fixes the compiler warning, but I still wonder: What is the purpose of binding `self.albumArtImageView?.image` if the result is not used? What is the purpose of assigning an image to `_` ?